# Installing selenium for Python in Windows 7

Tags: python, windows, selenium

I am trying to install "selenium-2.44.0" for "Python-3.4.1" on Windows 7 64 bit machine. I downloaded "selenium-2.44.0.tar.gz" and extracted to "Desktop" folder.

When I execute the command:

`C:\Python34>python C:\Users\User_Name\Desktop\selenium-2.44.0\setup.py install`

I get the following output:

```
running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
creating selenium.egg-info
writing selenium.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to selenium.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to selenium.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing manifest file 'selenium.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
warning: manifest_maker: standard file 'setup.py' not found

error: package directory 'py\selenium' does not exist

running install
running bdist_egg
running egg_info
creating selenium.egg-info
writing selenium.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to selenium.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to selenium.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing manifest file 'selenium.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
warning: manifest_maker: standard file 'setup.py' not found

error: package directory 'py\selenium' does not exist
```

But, within "selenium-2.44.0" folder, "py\selenium" directory exists.

Help!!

Thanks

Comment: This works correctly for me on Windows 7 using Python 3.4 and selenium 2.44.0. Not sure what's going on with yours. Maybe try reinstalling. Or you could try installing using pip: `c:\python34\scripts\pip.exe install selenium`

Comment: Hi Mike, I had tried that previously but got some error messages saying that pip is unable to find any packages named selenium. But, when i tried the pip command again, it reinstalled selenium. Let me use selenium and inform about the integrity consistency. Thanks, for your help!!

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in the comments, I can install selenium using the following when in the untarred archive's directory:

```
c:\Python34\python.exe setup.py install
```

This worked for me on Windows 7 with selenium 2.44.0.

Another way to install it would be to use pip:

```
c:\python34\scripts\pip.exe install selenium
```

Occasionally when installing packages on Windows, the package you download is corrupted or incomplete and you need to try reinstalling.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Mike. Appreciate it!!

Comment: The second worked perfectly!! Thank you! I used pip.exe install **-U** selenium as they suggest in their site: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium#downloads

Comment: how do you i update selenium in windows 10 cmd? i forgot what i used to do